# cannot delete google action as I must first delete a deleted dialogFlow agent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When I try and delete my Google Action I am told I must delete its DialogFlow agent first. However, this agent has already been deleted (I deleted all DialogFlow projects, in US, EU2, AS and AU).

I have tried deleting my DialogFlow account, but this did not help.

I have contacted [Actions on Google Developer support](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support) twice. On the first occasion they suggested I contact the [support page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support). On the second occasion I asked if they could manually delete my action, they said that only the creator of the action could do so.

I would appreciate your advice on the matter.
Best, Andy.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[DialogFlow Support](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support) advised I follow these steps:

> To shutdown your project:
>
> 1. Open the Settings page (found under IAM & admin) in the Google Cloud Console.
> 2. Open the Settings page
> 3. Click Select a project.
> 4. Select a project you want to delete, and click Open.
> 5. Click Shut down.
> 6. Enter the Project ID, then click Shut down.

This did not work. They then advised I delete project 'liens' via instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens#removing_liens_from_a_project), which involved opening a [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) for the project, typing in

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list
```

which gave you the lien's name (e.g. p1061081023732-l3d8032b3-ea2c-4683-ad48-5ca23ddd00e7) and then entering

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]
```

After doing this, I successfully deleted the pesky Google Action. Hurray!